# jquery to append a table to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i  have a `div id`.i have to append a table with values to the div.

```
<div id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px; "></div>
```

am doing follwing steps but it is not working.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getReports',
    cache: false
}).done(function (html) {
    if (html != "") {
        $('#testResult').show();
        var htm = "";

        var string1 = '<table border="1"><tr><td>No</td><td>Testcase</td> <td>OS</td> <td>Browser</td>  <td>Result</td></tr></table>';
        $.each(html, function (i, data) {

            string1 + = '<tr><td rowspan="3">1</td><td rowspan="3">' + data.status.test + '</td><td rowspan="3"><!--OS--></td><td>' + data.status.bwser + '</td> <td> ' + data.status.report + ' </td></tr>';
        });
        $('#testResult ').append(string1);
        $("#testResult").html("<br/><br/>");
        $("#testResult").html("<p>" + htm + "</p>");
    }

}).fail(function () {
    $("#testResult").html("Failed to run the test");
    $('#edit ').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: sorry...but it is not working

Comment: you are appending string1, then you overwrite "<br/><br/>" and again overwrite empty htm. does that make sense

Comment: You are overwriting the content with .html()

Comment: You can't `.append()` then use `.html()` which will replace the contents of the DIV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#testResult").html("<br/><br/>")` and `$("#testResult").html("<p>" + htm + "</p>")` will overwrite contents of your "testResult" DIV. So, replace this

```
$('#testResult ').append(string1);
      $("#testResult").html("<br/><br/>");
      $("#testResult").html("<p>" + htm + "</p>");   
}
```

with

```
$('#testResult ').append(string1);
      $("#testResult").append("<br/><br/>");
      $("#testResult").append("<p>" + htm + "</p>");   
}
```

**.append()**: Will add or append extra strings to the existing contents of the DIV 
where as

**.html()**: Will removes or overwrite the existing contents of the DIV with newer one.

This is the main difference between `.append()` and `.html()`.

Comment: @Pushkar: see my updated answer that should help you to understand main difference between both.

Answer (score 2):

edit this part

```
   $("#testResult").append("<br/><br/>");
  Remove this part-->
  $("#testResult").html("<p>" + htm + "</p>");
```

htm is empty string, as you never concatenate any string to it

Comment: adding break make some sense, but appending empty string variable  does not. thanks i ll' edit accordingly